# shorter URLs in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm creating a simple login application using Codeigniter and I have a simple question.
What is the best URL for this type of app ? Somewhere I see something like this :

```
example.com/account/login
example.com/account/register
```

Somewhere like this :

```
example.com/accounts/login
example.com/accounts/register
```

And somewhere like this :

```
example.com/login
example.com/register
```

Which one is better for a big project ? Which one do you suggest to use ?
Thanks

Comment: in short? use laravel

Comment: in shorten way, you should use the 3rd option. example.com/login

Comment: @dynamic Thanks, but I must user Codeigniter for my project

Comment: @Manmohan For 3rd option should I create two separate controllers `login` and `register` ? Or there is a better way ?

Comment: @TakaapoPage  you can set route it to one controller for that in codeigniter,

Comment: example.com/login
example.com/register - use it, and in application/config/routes.php redirect to your controller.

Comment: About routes in official documentation: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

the login for a user of example.com to get into their account:

```
example.com/account/login
example.com/account/register
```

example.com has an Admin login and the Admin has access to all the accounts:

```
example.com/accounts/login
example.com/accounts/register
```

there is no "account" per se, example.com is a service:

```
example.com/login
example.com/register
```

To be secure never put an account number or account db record id in any url for a page that you have to be logged in to see.